# Alamofire POST application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding

Tags: swift, post, alamofire, url-encoding

I am using Alamofire to POST request on a webservice. This webservice must have a parameter "time=00:00:00" in the exact format. However, if I create my parameters as `let params = ["time":"00:00:00"]` the request will fail. When I checked the value of the HTTPBody, it shows `time=16%3A00%3A00`. How do I make the request use colon character itself?

```
  let params = ["time":"00:00:00"]
  Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding(), headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
  // Check the http body.
  print(String(data: (response.request?.httpBody!)!, encoding: .utf8)
}
```

Comment: Try to edit  `URLEncoding()` to `JSONEncoding. default`

Answer (score 0):

```
let params = ["time":"00:00:00"]
  Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
  // Check the http body.
  print(String(data: (response.request?.httpBody!)!, encoding: .utf8)
}
```

encoding

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
let params: [String: Any] = ["first_param": "first_param_value",  "second_param": "second_param_value"]
        let headers:HTTPHeaders=[
          "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"]
    AF.request("<ENDPOINT_URL>", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 299).responseData { response in
        switch response.result {
                    case .success(let data):
                        do {
                            guard let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] else {
                                print("Error: Cannot convert data to JSON object")
                                return
                            }
                            guard let prettyJsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted) else {
                                print("Error: Cannot convert JSON object to Pretty JSON data")
                                return
                            }
                            guard let prettyPrintedJson = String(data: prettyJsonData, encoding: .utf8) else {
                                print("Error: Could print JSON in String")
                                return
                            }
                    
                            print(prettyPrintedJson)
                        } catch {
                            print("Error: Trying to convert JSON data to string")
                            return
                        }
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                }
    }
```